# Como retirar una cantidad concreta de un dato concreto de un ArrayList?

Tags: java, poo, arraylist, herencia, polimorfismo

Tengo un menu donde he ingresado una cantidad en  cuenta bancaria ( clase abstracta) con un add.
Es decir he creado el array List unico para cuenta bancaria, he preguntado los datos numcuenta y ingreso en diferentes scaner y he añadido estos datos en dos add.

uno para **cuenta corriente**

```
cuenta.add(new CuentaCorriente(numCuenta, ingreso));
```

Y otro para **cuenta Ahorro**

```
cuenta.add(new CuentaAhorro(numCuenta, ingreso));
```

Ahora deseo continuar mi menu retirando el dinero, pero me encuentro que no se como hacerlo exactamente.
He tratado de pedir la cuenta que deseo, si tengo por ejemplo la cuenta 123 y la cuenta 345, cuando se pregunta que cuenta deseo y respondo la 345 , que se muestre esta por pantalla unicamente y a continuación me pregunte que cantidad deseo retirar, colocandole un numero que restara al saldo total.

```
public static void retirar() {
    String respuesta;
    double respuesta2;
    double saldoAhora;

    System.out.println("Cual es la cuenta que desea?");
    respuesta = lector.nextLine();

    if(cuenta.size() > 0 ) {
        for(CuentaBancaria cb: cuenta) {
            if(cb.numCuenta.equalsIgnoreCase(respuesta)) {
            System.out.println("\n=*=*=Su cuenta=*=*=");
            System.out.println("\n"+cb.toString()+"\n");
            cuenta.lastIndexOf(respuesta);

            System.out.println("Que cantidad desea retirar??");
            respuesta2 = lector.nextInt();

            saldoAhora=cb.saldo-respuesta2;

            cuenta.set(1,saldoAhora);
            }

        }   

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("---------------\nNo hay ninguna Cuenta\n---------------");
    }

}
```

estas son las variables de la **clase abstracta CuentaBancaria**:

```
String numCuenta;
private final double INTERESANUAL;
private double saldo;
private double total;
private double ingreso;
private double transferencia;
```

Constructor:

```
public CuentaBancaria(String numCuenta) {
        this.INTERESANUAL = 20;
        this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
    }

public CuentaBancaria(String numCuenta, double ingreso) {
    this.INTERESANUAL = 20;
    this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
    this.ingreso = ingreso;
}

//getters y setters .....
```

este es el constructor de **Cuenta corriente**:

```
public CuentaCorriente(String numCuenta, double ingreso) {
    super(numCuenta, ingreso);
}
```

no tiene ninguna variable y solo contiene otro metodo para calcular el interes

esta es la variable y el constructor de **Cuenta Ahorro**:

```
private final double SALDOMINIMO;

    public CuentaAhorro(String numCuenta,double ingreso) {
        super(numCuenta, ingreso);
        this.SALDOMINIMO = 300;
    }
```

Tambien dispone de un metodo para calcular el interes.

Estoy haciendo algo incorrectamente? como seria esto?

**Esto seria por pantalla lo que se ve:**

```
=*=*=*= Bienvenido al banco Java =*=*=*=
1.-Ingresar dinero
2.-Consultar Cuentas
3.-Retirar dinero
4.-Trasferencia  otra cuenta
5.-Salir
1
Indique el numero de su cuenta:
123
Indique la cantidad que desea ingresar
345
Que tipo de cuenta desea?
1.-Cuenta corriente
2.-Cuenta Ahorro
1
=*=*=*= Bienvenido al banco Java =*=*=*=
1.-Ingresar dinero
2.-Consultar Cuentas
3.-Retirar dinero
4.-Trasferencia  otra cuenta
5.-Salir
2

=*=*=Cuentas=*=*=

CuentaCorriente -->numero de Cuenta=123, interes=20.0, saldo=345.0, ingreso=345.0, transferencia=0.0, , Saldo total con Interes=2345.0

=*=*=*= Bienvenido al banco Java =*=*=*=
1.-Ingresar dinero
2.-Consultar Cuentas
3.-Retirar dinero
4.-Trasferencia  otra cuenta
5.-Salir
2

=*=*=Cuentas=*=*=

CuentaCorriente -->numero de Cuenta=123, interes=20.0, saldo=345.0, ingreso=345.0, transferencia=0.0, , Saldo total con Interes=2345.0

=*=*=*= Bienvenido al banco Java =*=*=*=
1.-Ingresar dinero
2.-Consultar Cuentas
3.-Retirar dinero
4.-Trasferencia  otra cuenta
5.-Salir
3
Cual es la cuenta que desea?
123

=*=*=Su cuenta=*=*=

CuentaCorriente -->numero de Cuenta=123, interes=20.0, saldo=345.0, ingreso=345.0, transferencia=0.0, , Saldo total con Interes=2345.0

-1
Que cantidad desea retirar??
23
=*=*=*= Bienvenido al banco Java =*=*=*=
1.-Ingresar dinero
2.-Consultar Cuentas
3.-Retirar dinero
4.-Trasferencia  otra cuenta
5.-Salir
2

=*=*=Cuentas=*=*=

CuentaCorriente -->numero de Cuenta=123, interes=20.0, saldo=345.0, ingreso=345.0, transferencia=0.0, , Saldo total con Interes=2345.0

=*=*=*= Bienvenido al banco Java =*=*=*=
1.-Ingresar dinero
2.-Consultar Cuentas
3.-Retirar dinero
4.-Trasferencia  otra cuenta
5.-Salir
```

**edit:**
Añado metodo saldoTotal() de CuentaBancaria que es el que da el saldo:

```
public double saldoTotal() {
        double total = 0;
        if (setTransferencia(transferencia)==false) {
        total=this.saldo+this.ingreso;
        return total;
        }
        else {
            total=this.saldo+this.ingreso+this.transferencia;
        return total;
        }
    }
```

tengo un getter y un setter para saldo pero nunca añaden el saldo correctamente por eso cree este metodo, en vez de sacar en el toString de cuentaBancaria el saldo llamo a saldoTotal() y me dice el saldo actual con el ingreso, pero si retiro se suma el saldoTotal(), con la cantidad anterior menos lo que he quitado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Como retirar una cantidad concreta de un dato concreto de un ArrayList?

Lo único que debes hacer es modificar el atributo (`saldo`) del objeto (ya sea `cuentaCorriente` o `cuentaAhorro`).

Así que el problema radica en esta línea:

```java
saldoAhora=cb.saldo-respuesta2;
```

En ningún momento modificas el atributo `saldo` de la clase `CuentaBancaria` y por esa razón, el valor se pierde, ya que lo estás almacenando en una variable local llamada `saldoAhora` (su contenido se libera de memoria cuando el método `retirar` termine su ejecución).

La forma correcta de restar el dinero actual que tenga el atributo `saldo`, es de la siguiente manera:

```java
cb.saldo = cb.saldo - respuesta2;
```

O también podrías usar el operador `-=`:

```java
cb.saldo -= respuesta2;
```

También podías haber asignado el valor que tenga la variable `saldoAhora` en `cb.saldo`.

```java
saldoAhora=cb.saldo-respuesta2;
cb.saldo = saldoAhora;
```

Sin embargo, veo la variable `saldoAhora` como innecesaria, debido a que, se le puede asignar directamente el valor a `cb.saldo`.

También debemos tomar en cuenta que al retirar el dinero, se necesita detectar si hay el monto suficiente para retirar, de lo contrario, debería mandar un mensaje de error al usuario:

```java
if(cb.saldo < respuesta2)
{
    System.out.println("Error: No hay dinero suficiente para retirar");
}
else
{
    cb.saldo -= respuesta2;
}
```

También se necesita verificar si el monto es válido, el usuario no debería ingresar valores menores o iguales a `0`. No tendría sentido introducir `-500` o `0` como saldo.

El código quedaría así:

```java
if(respuesta2 <= 0)
{
    System.out.println("Has ingresado un monto invalido");
}
else if(cb.saldo < respuesta2)
{
    System.out.println("Error: No hay dinero suficiente para retirar");
}
else
{
    cb.saldo -= respuesta2;
}
```

Todo el código de arriba se lo podría agregar en algún bucle para preguntarle al usuario que vuelva a introducir un monto válido o que no se pase del monto actual.

Otro error que tienes en tu código es la siguiente línea:

```java
cuenta.set(1,saldoAhora);
```

El método [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) sirve para alterar el contenido de `X` posición del `ArrayList`. Sin embargo, lo estás usando mal, debido a que, el segundo parámetro de dicho método, es de tipo `T`.

**¿Qué quiere decir esto?**

Que al momento de instanciar la clase genérica (`ArrayList`), se pasó un argumento (en este caso es el tipo `CuentaBancaria`) al parámetro `T` de la clase genérica `ArrayList`, esto quiere decir, que sólo se podrá pasar en el segundo parámetro del método `set` referencias de objetos que sean derivadas del tipo `T` (en este caso deben ser clases derivadas de `CuentaBancaria`).

Por lo tanto, la forma correcta de hacerlo sería de esta forma:

```java
//El tipo CuentaAhorro es derivado de CuentaBancaria
cuenta.set(1, new CuentaAhorro(...));
```

Sin embargo, en tu caso es innecesario usar el método `set`, por lo tanto, lo podríamos eliminar.

**¿Por qué es innecesario?**

Simple. Porque lo que nos interesa es **modificar/alterar** el contenido de un atributo de un objeto. Al usar el método `set`, estaríamos perdiendo la referencia del objeto (en este caso de la posición `1` del `ArrayList`).

Teniendo en cuenta todos los puntos que mencioné anteriormente, el código completo quedaría de esta manera:

```java
for(CuentaBancaria cb: cuenta) 
{
    if(cb.numCuenta.equalsIgnoreCase(respuesta))
    {
        System.out.println("\n=*=*=Su cuenta=*=*=");
        System.out.println("\n"+cb.toString()+"\n");
        cuenta.lastIndexOf(respuesta);

        System.out.println("Que cantidad desea retirar??");
        respuesta2 = lector.nextInt();

        if(respuesta2 <= 0)
            System.out.println("Has ingresado un monto invalido");
        else if(cb.saldo < respuesta2)
            System.out.println("Error: No hay dinero suficiente para retirar");
        else
            cb.saldo -= respuesta2;
    }
}
```

**Recomendación:**

Los nombres de las variables deben ser de acuerdo al contexto del problema. En tu caso, has puesto como nombre `respuesta` y `respuesta2`, básicamente esos identificadores no me dan ningún significado.

En vez de declararlo como `respuesta`:

```
String respuesta;
```

Podrías asignarle como nombre: `numCuenta_client`. Indicando que nos referimos al número de cuenta de un cliente.

En cuestión con el nombre `respuesta2`, se lo podría reemplazar por `cant_retirar` (el identificador puede variar, simplemente es un ejemplo), en la cual, indica que cantidad se requiere retirar.

Comment: Creo que estoy haciendo algo mal, en vez de restarme la cantidad que deseo cuando consulto el saldo de la cuenta hay el saldo que habia + el saldo menos la cantidad, es decir si yo tenia 123 y quito 2 me salen 244, voy a editar la pregunta y abajo añado lo que creo que puede ser el problema

Comment: @azucarilla No se entiende tu problema. La falla está en el método `retirar`, ¿por qué estaría en el método `saldoTotal()`? Tuve una falla al momento de escribir el código en mi respuesta, en vez de escribir `cb.saldo -= respuesta2`, había puesto: `saldoAhora -= respuesta2`. Ya lo corregí.

Comment: Creo que el fallo fue ese pero llevo tanto rato dandole vueltas que me he mareado y pensaba que era por el saldo total ya lo he corregido ahora si funciona muchisimas gracias!!!!!